# Process a dataTask GET request on background

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have an API to get about 1000 records from a GET request. Currently I'm using dataTask to get the content via URLSession. Complication is the request just freeze as soon as it enters to the background mode. When i did some research I found out that NSURLSessionDataTask doest support the background mode and instead I have to use downloadTask with backgroundSessionConfiguration. Hence, I have troubles with modifying my code accordingly. My current code as bellow.

```
class Network: NSObject {

 //Singleton
  public static var shared: Network {

    if networkCalls == nil {
        networkCalls = Network()
    }
    return networkCalls!

  }


 //Place where issue is converting the dataTask to downloadTask
  private func performWebServiceRequest <T: Codable>(type: T.Type, with url: URL, contentType: CONTENT_TYPE? = nil, requestType: String, paramData: T? = nil, requestOptions: [String: String]?, responseStructure: String, successBlock: @escaping SuccessBlock, failureBlock: @escaping FailureBlock) {

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = requestType // As in "POST", "GET", "PUT" or "DELETE"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData


   let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data: Data = data, let response: URLResponse = response, error == nil else 
      {
        failureBlock(0, ERROR_MESSAGE)
      }

      let responseStatusCode: Int =  (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode


       if reponseStatusCode == 200 {


                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
                    successBlock(result)

                } catch {

                    failureBlock(0,"Error")
                }
       }

     }

     task.resume()
  }

}
```

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of showing a progress wheel or something while your app downloads those records?

Comment: As i mentioned in the question when you use session.dataTask, the request gets frozen when it enters the background mode

Comment: You can’t download data to memory if your App goes to the background. Your only option is downloadTask

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background

Comment: @LeoDabus yes i know that and i have mentioned that in the question too. All what im asking is a code snippet to modify my one

Comment: Not related to your question but if you need a mutable url request all you need is `var request = URLRequest(...`

Comment: where is CONTENT_TYPE declared? Same applies to SuccessBlock and FailureBlock

Comment: You should use Swift `Result` instead of creating your own SuccessBlock and FailureBlock

Comment: I would also separate upload and download into two different methods